# C# XNA, handling lots of objects,

Tags: c#, xna

I am creating a game and need some help handling a bunch of objects, like about 10000, in my game i am generating a random amount of rocks, in random positions around a 1mil by 1mil map, I am adding the objects to a list and updating and drawing them like that but it is running so slow. I think some help in this matter would really help a lot of learners wanting to handle many objects.
 Here is my generation code:

```
public void WorldGeneration()
    {
        //Random Compatibility
        Random rdm = new Random();

        //Tile Variables
        int tileType;
        int tileCount = 0;
        Rock nearestRock;

        //Initialize Coordinates
        Vector2 tileSize = new Vector2(48f, 48f);
        Vector2 currentGenVector = new Vector2(48f, 48f);
        int worldTiles = 1000000;

        //Do tile generation
        for(int tile = 1; tile <= worldTiles; tile += 1)
        {   
            //Generate Classes
            tileType = rdm.Next(0, 42);
            if (tileType == 1)
            {
                if (rocks.Count != 0)
                {
                    //Check Rock Distance
                    nearestRock = rocks.FirstOrDefault(x => Vector2.Distance(x.Location, currentGenVector) < 128);
                    if (nearestRock == null)
                    {
                        Rock rock = new Rock(rockSprite, currentGenVector);
                        rocks.Add(rock);
                    }
                }
                if (rocks.Count == 0)
                {
                    Rock rock = new Rock(rockSprite, currentGenVector);
                    rocks.Add(rock);
                }
            }

            //Move Generation Tile
            if (tileCount == worldTiles / 1000)
            {
                currentGenVector.X = tileSize.X;
                currentGenVector.Y += tileSize.Y;
                tileCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                currentGenVector.X += tileSize.X;
            }
            //Keep Count of Tiles per layer.
            tileCount += 1;
        }
```

And here is my rock code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace Game2
{
    class Rock
    {
        //Draw Support
        Texture2D sprite;
        Rectangle drawRectangle;

    //Support
    Vector2 location;
    bool updating = false;

    //Active
    bool active = true;

    public Rock(Texture2D sprite, Vector2 location)
    {
        //Initialize Location/Drawing
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.location = location;

        drawRectangle.Width = sprite.Width;
        drawRectangle.Height = sprite.Height;

        drawRectangle.X = (int)location.X - sprite.Width / 2;
        drawRectangle.Y = (int)location.Y - sprite.Height / 2;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime, MouseState mouse)
    {
        //Mining
        if (drawRectangle.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
        {
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                location.X = -800;
                location.Y = -800;
            }
        }
        drawRectangle.X = (int)location.X;
        drawRectangle.Y = (int)location.Y;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        //Draws The Sprite
        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, drawRectangle, Color.White);
    }

    //Get Location
    public Vector2 Location
    {
        get { return location; }
    }
    public bool Updating
    {
        get { return updating; }
    }
    public void setUpdating(bool updating)
    {
        this.updating = updating;
    }
    public Rectangle DrawRectangle
    {
        get { return drawRectangle; }
    }
}
}
```

I'm just asking for some tips on how to handle all these objects,
pls help is appreciated

Comment: Which is slow? The update loop or the draw loop? You could ignore rocks that aren't in the current viewport.

Comment: I think it is the Update loop but I will give it a try, how would i do that? Sorry i'm new to XNA and C# and still learning.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle many objects is that I create a function which calculates the distance between two vectors and then use it to check if the current object is close enough to be drawn.

```
//Distance checking code
public float GetDistance(Vector2 v1, Vector2 v2){
    float d = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs((v1.X * v1.X) - (v2.X * v2.X)) 
    + Math.Abs((v1.Y * v1.Y) - (v2.Y * v2.Y)));
return d;
}

//example of using the Distance Check
if(GetDistance(player.position, rock.position) < 1280){
    rock.Update();
}
```

This is just from the top of my head though, so the code may not work properly, but I think it's enough to get you started. Good luck!